# Cannot load PNG images from URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to load a PNG from a URL, but I always get a `nil` data.

The following is my code.

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
            NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: _artworkCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl]];
            if ( data == nil ){
                artworksCollectionCell.artworkImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-unavailable"];
                return;
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
                artworksCollectionCell.artworkImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
            });
        });
```

I also attempted to use the `setImageWithURL` from `set-image` library

```
artworksCollectionCell.artworkImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_artworkCollectionsArray[indexPath.row].imageUrl] placeholderImage:NO_IMAGE];
```

But can't load any image as well.

Comment: Is the URL local (file system URL)?

Comment: @vadian nope, i tried to load the image form this url https://bammedia.blob.core.windows.net/images/featured_images/Jewellery%20&%20Gems1502684617.png

Comment: @progammingBeignner I'm able to load the image with the URL given.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-initwithcontentsofurl says you should not use this method to load from network-based url

Comment: When I use your url in your code (slight changes since i do not have your Objects and project, thus setting it to a image view using your url ) it works by me as well...